# How to send data from API to another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, api, local-storage

Im using a TMDB API to search for movies and add them to a watchlist.

In this javascript function im getting movie details based on user input and rendering the results to html using bootstrap.

```
const searchMovie =  async (searchInput) => {
    try { 
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${searchInput}&page=1&include_adult=false `)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        let movies = response.data.results;
        let displayMovies = '';
        $.each(movies, (index, movie) => {
          displayMovies += `
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="well text-center">
          <a href="https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/${movie.movie_id} target="_blank"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${movie.poster_path}"></a>
            <h5>${movie.title}</h5>
            <h4>${movie.release_date}<h4>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Add to watchlist</a>
          </div>
        </div>
          `;
        });
        
        $('#movies').html(displayMovies);
      })
    }catch(error) {
     console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I have another html file called **watchlist.html** that i want to send the movie selected from the search results to that file and build a watchlist.

Comment: You're extracting items from an object called `movie` and storing them in a different object, also called `movie`. Something's not right there. How does your event handler get access to the original `movie` object?

Comment: I just changed the object name that might interfere with the object 'movie' in my for each and is still not working. This is my first time using local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one before stringify

```
var obj = JSON.parse(movie);
localStorage.setItem('selectedMovie', JSON.stringify(obj));
```