# How to send data fetched from API to another HTML file using localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, local-storage

Im using a TMDB API to search for movies and add them to a watchlist. In this javascript function im getting movie details based on user input and rendering the results to html using bootstrap.

```
const searchMovie =  async (searchInput) => {
    try { 
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${searchInput}&page=1&include_adult=false `)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        let movies = response.data.results;
        let displayMovies = '';
        $.each(movies, (index, movie) => {
          displayMovies += `
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="well text-center">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${movie.poster_path}"></a>
            <h5>${movie.title}</h5>
            <h4>${movie.release_date}<h4>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="add-movie-button" href="#">Add to watchlist</a>
          </div>
        </div>
          `;
        });
        
        $('#movies').html(displayMovies);
      })
    }catch(error) {
     console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I have another html file called watchlist.html that i want to send the movie selected from the search results to that file and build a watchlist.

I'm trying to use the next code below but it is not saving the data in local storage.

First HTML file (search results):

```
// Save the movie data in localStorage when the "Add to watchlist" button is clicked
$('#add-movie-button').on('click', () => {
          let movie = {
            poster: movie.poster_path,
            title: movie.title,
            releaseDate: movie.release_date,
            
          };
        
          localStorage.setItem('selectedMovie', JSON.stringify(movie));
        });
```

Second HTML file (watchlist):

```
 // Retrieve the selected movie from localStorage and display it on the page
 let selectedMovie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedMovie'));
 if (selectedMovie) {
   `<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="well text-center">
    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${poster}"></a>
     <h5>${title}</h5>
     <h4>${releaseDate}<h4>
   </div>
 </div>`;
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74664085/how-to-send-data-from-api-to-another-html-filehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/74664085/how-to-send-data-from-api-to-another-html-file under a different account